# Swift import CoreGraphics.CGBase VS. import CoreGraphics causes LLDB malfunctioning

Tags: ios, swift

I have some swift code files in my Objective-C based project.

I can compile it and they are playing well with each other.

The swift code does

`import CoreGraphics.CGBase`

However, when I was debugging the swift code,
I will get:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'CGBase' from AST context
```

If I replace `import CoreGraphics.CGBase` to `import CoreGraphics`, issue is gone.

Can anyone explain what the side effect if I use import CoreGraphics? And is this a bug for LLDB or xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side effect is that your program works, because `CoreGraphics` is the framework you're supposed to import. `CoreGraphics.CGBase` is an implementation detail and you shouldn't import it directly.

Comment: well, I don't use `import CoreGraphics.CGBase`. It is open source project who uses it. At first, I think this narrows down to the specific module it wants to use, and it does not import other useless modules for app performance or compiling performance. could you elaberate what's the difference between `import CoreGraphics.CGBase` and `import CoreGraphics` ? Why I shouldn't use it directly?